# How can i use jsx instead of js extension in react boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx, boilerplate

I just want to add jsx Page in the https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/

Below is what i want to add Password forgot page jsx file content.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

class PwdForgotPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        Password forgot.
        <button className="btn btn-link">Back</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { registering } = state.registration;
  return {
    registering,
  };
}

const connectedPwdForgotPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(PwdForgotPage);
export { connectedPwdForgotPage as PwdForgotPage };
```

But if i use jsx extension, failed to run as below.

```
Module parse failed: C:\.....\frontend\app\containers\PwdForgotPage\PwdForgotPage.jsx Unexpected token (8:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render() {
|     return (
|       <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
|         Password forgot.
|         <button className="btn btn-link">Back</button>
```

If i use js extension, it works.
How do i change the config in the boilerplate for jsx extension support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `jsx` extension to the rule  in webpack config that enables babel `babel-loader`.

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/, // notice optional x?
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: options.babelQuery,
    },
  },
```

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/webpack/webpack.base.babel.js#L23

Or subjectively more readable `/\.(js|jsx)$/`

Answer (score 0):

From your existing project, you can run:

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

Then .jsx files will be interpreted.

For more information, check following site:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/